# bash - using array with find command

Tags: arrays, bash, find

I want to append found directories to array.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=()
find . ! \( \( -path './android/out' -o -path './.repo' \) -prune \) -type d -name prebuilts | while read file; do
  echo "FILES -->$file"
  FILES+=("$file")
done
echo "num of FILES: ${#FILES[@]}"
echo "FILES: ${FILES[@]}"
```

but result as below:

```
FILES -->./android/test/vts/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/system/apex/shim/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/system/sepolicy/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/vendor/tvstorm/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/vendor/dmt/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/kernel/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/developers/build/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/external/selinux/prebuilts
FILES -->./android/development/vndk/tools/header-checker/tests/integration/version_script_example/prebuilts
num of FILES: 0
FILES:
```

Why does num of array is 0?

Comment: Aside: If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, `setopt extended_glob` and then `FILES=( **/prebuilts~android/out/*(#q/) )`. No `find` needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the array after `|`, i.e. in a subshell. Changes from the subshell don't propagate to the parent shell.

Use process substitution instead:

```sh
while read file; do
    echo "FILES -->$file"
    FILES+=("$file")
done < <(find . ! \( \( -path './android/out' -o -path './.repo' \) -prune \) -type d -name prebuilts)
```

If you don't need job control, you can also `shopt -s lastpipe` to run the last command in a pipeline in the current shell.

Comment: Or do a `shopt -s lastpipe` first.